# Load different kubectl configs beside default one in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kubernetes

Besides my default configuration file in ~/.kube/config, I have additional ones which I use in my Terminal:

```
> echo $KUBECONFIG
~/.kube/customer.yml:~/.kube/config
```

This is defined in my ~/.zshrc and of course IntelliJ cannot find that by default. The cluster configured in the default successfully shows up in the *Services* Tab.

**Question**: Is there a way to tell IntelliJ the value of my KUBECONFIG environment variable?

Comment: Please try launching IDEA via shell script, using zsh interpreter.

Comment: Good idea, but then I see "Unknown cluster [All Namespace]" in IDEA and no other clusters show up - even the one from ~/.kube/config. The cli script was generated by Toolbox.